# What is the Better way to manage posts in Wordpress?

Tags: posts, management

I am looking for a plugin or a "tool" that would mod the administration interface and would allow me to mass edit the posts.

Currently the posts are paginated by 20 post per page, if i have to turn 1000 post into drafts or delete them - i have to browse multiple pages.

Same for changing categories or making mass changes to posts.

This can be quite a pain for big blogs with many posts

So i was wondering, is there a "Better" way to manage posts in wordpress ?

What would you recommend ?

i am poking around the topic of post management and would love to hear from you

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In paginated areas in admin interface you can click *Screen options* (upper right) and change amount of items per page to display.

Comment: would it be efficient to load more than 100 post per page ? - i am just wondering if there are other "admin interfaces" for post management that i could use.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is the only other good one I know of ;)

Comment: Define efficient? :) Likely it would be slow (well, depends on your server) and I won't keep setting at >100 constantly. By the way I forgot to mention that bulk operations in admin can't handle too many items at once (on SQL level, query gets broken). Limit is something between 200-250.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this more often I would write some sql or perl or whatever scripts for each operation.
First run it locally against a local test server.
then replace the database settings to the remote database and run the script again.

After some time you have a lot of perl scripts then combine the different settings in one .ini file to read the config from that for all of them.

I uploaded a perl script that does some database interaction here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-23-compatible-wordpress-delicious-daily-synchronization-script/

just replace the sql statements with the statements you need and the code with the code you need, you can probably just delete a lot of stuff keeping the database connection, the sql statements and a quick "run the sql statement".

The benefit of running perl above direct sql is that you have a second layer to provide logging, some more easier programming and... it has a gazillion modules such as "delicious lib" so that you can extend it easily with all kinds of ideas. It also makes your code much more re-usable and you can re-use settings centrally from an .ini file etc...